# Box2d MovieClip to original position

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I want to try a simple task where if i move a object inside the world and then press a button it should go back to its original position , but its not working , below is the code i am using - the file is here - http://www.fastswf.com/yAnIvBs (when i remove the event listener)

with event listener - http://www.fastswf.com/rpYsIt8

////////======================== 
    stop();

```
var startXPos:Number = level1WorldObj.box1.x;
var startYPos:Number = level1WorldObj.box1.y;

function areaS(e:Event) {



level1WorldObj.box1.y= startYPos;
level1WorldObj.box1.x= startXPos;
level1WorldObj.box1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, areaS);


}

but1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nClick3);

function nClick3(event:MouseEvent):void{
level1WorldObj.box1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, areaS);
level1WorldObj.box1.y= startYPos;
level1WorldObj.box1.x= startXPos;
}
```

/////////////////======================

Now i want to be able to do it many time so i kept the variables that detect the initial x, y as global ...

Here you can see how it behaves in debugdraw mode , strangely only the clip moves not the actual body - http://www.fastswf.com/-Ijkta4

Can some one please guide me here ...

Thanks in advance ...

Jin

Answer (score 1):

The graphics that you see (`box1`) aren't related to the physical object behind the scenes - you're currently only moving the graphics not the object itself.

You need to use either `SetPosition()` or `SetTransform()` on the `b2Body` of the object

**Edit 07/7**

As you're using the Box2D World Construction Kit, I took a look at the source code (available here: https://github.com/jesses/wck). The main class seems to be `BodyShape` (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jesses/wck/master/wck/BodyShape.as).

Looking through it, you should be able to access the `b2Body` directly. If it's `null` (which is probably the source of the `TypeError` that you're getting, then you haven't called `createBody()`, which is what actually takes all of your properties as creates the physical object behind the scenes.

Once you have a `b2Body`, if you want to position it based on the graphics, there's a function `syncTransform()` to do just that.

You should turn on `debugDraw` on your `World` class to make it easier to see what's going on in the background. NOTE: this needs to be done before calling `create()`

Comment: thanks a lot , yes that seems to be the case but my issue is after converting the body to a movie clip i have names it box1(instance name) so why is it not getting moved , i am not calling them via code , but the body is already in the library by name of say purple, so how can i get its coordinates ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your explanation. You don't *convert* a `b2Body` to a `MovieClip`; you *associate* some graphics with it. To move the graphics, your flow goes something like: 1) update `b2Body` object, 2) convert `b2Body` position to pixel coords (Box2D is in meters), 3) update associated graphics position

Comment: Normally, what you'd do it store a reference to the graphics `MovieClip` on the `b2Body` using `SetUserData()`. You then store your body however you want so you can access it later (e.g. as a class property, or in an array), then you can update it as you want, and update the graphics using `GetUserData()`

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your time and explanation - i am using an extension of box2d which allows us to create shapes , world , just like we can make a movieclip or a button and then we can assign values to them from a property panel , like gravity , damping etc... So i took a box image convert in to a shape and inside the world  i try and reposition it ...so is there a way that if we get say a circle that is there in library already with all the property and that we can use it inside the world to affect the real body as well ... sorry if i am not clear , but there seems to some word limit here

Comment: Can you link to the extension so I can see what you mean? When you create `box1`, are you doing it through a GUI, or through code. If it's through code, can you paste your sample?

Comment: In either case, in the swf you posted, you can drag the box to throw it around, so you should be able to get the `b2Body` in question. Once you have this, just call `SetPosition()` on it (remember to convert your desired pixel coords to world units)

Comment: Hi, here is the link - http://www.sideroller.com/wck/ and a link to forum - http://box2d.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=19 , now i have been able to remove the box and add a new box dynamically but the new box that is added does not seem to have the properties i want , for example i mention - myWolrd1.box1.type='Static'; to make it static on being added but it does not seem to pick up those properties ..

Comment: when i am trying this -

var startXPos:Number= level1WorldObj.box1.b2body.GetPosition().x;

i am getting an error - TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at wck::WCK/frame1()[wck.WCK::frame1:3]

what might be wrong here , can you please guide ...

Comment: I updated my answer with more info - the null object error you're getting is probably because the `b2Body` property is null (`trace` it out to be sure), meaning you haven't called `createBody()` on your object yet

Comment: the strange thing is when i trace it out it gives a value of the position , but when i try and assign it to a number variable it gives the null object error, so the level1WorldObj.box1.b2body.GetPosition().x is giving me value but the question is how can i use it .... once again thanks a lot for  this amazing support ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find solution to this problem , i found the starting point by using this -

trace(level1WorldObj.box1.b2body.GetPosition().x);
trace(level1WorldObj.box1.b2body.GetPosition().y);

then once i had the position manually i took down the coordinates and  used the below code ....

level1WorldObj.box1.b2body.SetTransform(new V2(-2, 2),0 );

Thanks @divillysausages for all the help ...

Regards